# XPath Only Selects Part of Href

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I've searched everywhere and can't find anything that helps.  I am trying to extract information from a page using Scrapy.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<a Href="JavaScript:ShowParts('1','58537','RP45%2C+RP60+Compactors+w%2FHatz+1D81S+Eng%2E');">RP45, RP60 Compactors w/Hatz 1D81S Eng.</a>
```

I want everything starting with after Href=" and before ');  Here is my code.

```
def parseEngines(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    engines = hxs.select("//a/@href")
    print engines
```

When I print engines I should be getting something like this:

```
JavaScript:ShowParts('1','58537','RP45%2C+RP60+Compactors+w%2FHatz+1D81S+Eng%2E');
```

But instead I get only this:

```
JavaScript:ShowParts('1','58537','RP45%2
```

And that's it.  Why am I only getting half of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hxs.select("//a/@href")` returns a `HtmlXPathSelector` object, not the result you want. And the string representation of the object is not full. Use:

```
engines = hxs.select("//a/@href").extract()
print engines
```

You can get what you want. Demo:

```
>>> a = HtmlXPathSelector(text=s)
>>> a
<HtmlXPathSelector xpath=None data=u'<html><body><a href="JavaScript:ShowPart'>
>>> a.select("//a/@href")
[<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//a/@href' data=u"JavaScript:ShowParts('1','58537','RP45%2">]
>>> a.select("//a/@href").extract()
[u"JavaScript:ShowParts('1','58537','RP45%2C+RP60+Compactors+w%2FHatz+1D81S+Eng%2E');"]
```